# SQL Server : setting two variables month and year for previous month, year roll over safe

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to basically dynamically set two variables (@month and @year) to be whatever the previous month and year were.

So in today's case `@month = 7` and `@year = 2012`

But I want something safe for the year roll around, so if it's `1/1/2013` I would get `@month = 12` and `@year = 2012`.

Thanks!

This is what I have.

```
declare @month              int
declare @year               int

set @month = month (getDate ())-1
set @year = 2012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) to subtract a month from the current date, then grab the `MONTH` and `YEAR` portions:

```
DECLARE @monthAgo dateTime
DECLARE @month int
DECLARE @year int

SET @monthAgo = DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
SET @month = MONTH(@monthAgo)
SET @year = YEAR(@monthAgo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Shown in steps.  You can modify the value assigned to `@Now` to test.

```
DECLARE @Now DateTime = GETDATE();
DECLARE @Then DateTime = DATEADD(Month, -1, @Now);

DECLARE @Month Int = DATEPART(Month, @Then);
DECLARE @Year Int = DATEPART(Year, @Then);

SELECT @Month, @Year;
```

Answer (score 1):

can you not just add, after what you already have:

```
if @month = 0
begin
  set @month = 12
  set @year = @year - 1
end
```

Comment: The month before January is January?  And the prior year is always 2011?

Answer (score 0):

As a single query, this gives the first day of last month:

```
select DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'20001201')
```

You can, if you choose, pull that apart into two separate variables, but why bother? (I assume the rest of what you're doing is working with `datetime`s also, rather than `int`s)

---

The two `datetime` strings above are selected because they have the desired relationship between them - that the second starts 1 month before the first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @month int
declare @year int
Declare @dt datetime=getdate()
set @month = DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(mm,-1,@dt))
select @month
set @year = DATEPART(yy,DATEADD(mm,-1,@dt))
select @year
```

Comment: Two calls to `GetDate()` are inviting some debugging fun in the future.

Comment: I did not get what are you saying here pls explain.

Comment: When the first returns 12/31/2041 23:59:59.997 and the second returns 01/01/2042 00:00:00.000 the calulations will be out of synchronization.  Almost any TSQL code needing the current date/time more than once should capture it in a variable and use that value throughout.  The obvious exception is when capturing the start and end times of an operation for performance analysis.

Comment: ohh ok.Thats right.So i have changed the query above pls check.